# Source of insert\update operation

Tags: acumatica

Say you customized a RowPersisted event. How would you know if the operation was invoked thru an API or not ? I only want to execute my customization if the update was done thru REST API for example.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, If you want your code to be executed only from API calls, you can add your code inside this if condition

```
if (Base.IsImport) 
{
 //your code
}
```

Comment: There is also IsContractBasedAPI which i would include. I think IsImport is using screen based API or import scenario. Also IsMobile for use from mobile device. All found on the graph instance

Comment: Thanks for more info Brendan.